# How come resolve-QName() is an unknown XSLT function when using XslCompiledTransform?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, wsdl, xslcompiledtransform

I try to transform a WSDL 1.1 to WSDL 2.0 using the XSLT 2.0 stylesheet from [W3.org WSDL 1.1 to WSDL 2.0 convertor](http://www.w3.org/2006/02/WSDLConvert.html).

I'm working in .NET (C#) using the XslCompiledTransform.

Anyone has an idea why I get the "resolve-QName() is an unknown XSLT function" exception ?

Any workarounds ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET does not support XSLT 2.0.